# If start text "((^U.S. ex rel )|(^Will of ))" and contains text 'v' then how to add text before 'v' - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

If Start text `((^U.S. ex rel )|(^Will of ))` and `contains` text `v` then how to Insert start text `((^U.S. ex rel )|(^Will of ))` before `v` text other wise Insert text end?
**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <p><italic>U.S. ex rel Alcohol Found. v Kalmanovitz</italic> (SD NY 2002) 186 F Supp 2d 458</p>
    <p><italic>U.S. ex rel Guardiola v Renown Health</italic> (D Nev, Aug. 25, 2015, No. 3:12&#x2013;cv&#x2013;00295-LRH-VPC) 2015 US Dist Lexis 112511</p>
    <p><italic>Will of Guardiola Renown Health</italic> (D Nev, Aug. 25, 2015, No. 3:12&#x2013;cv&#x2013;00295-LRH-VPC) 2015 US Dist Lexis 112511</p>
</root>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="italic">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="((^U.S. ex rel )|(^Will of ))(.+)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(regex-group(4), ', ', regex-group(1)))"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expect Output**

```
 <root>
    <p>Alcohol Found., U.S. ex rel v Kalmanovitz (SD NY 2002) 186 F Supp 2d 458</p>
    <p>Guardiola, U.S. ex rel v Renown Health (D Nev, Aug. 25, 2015, No. 3:12–cv–00295-LRH-VPC) 2015 US Dist Lexis 112511</p>
    <p>Guardiola Renown Health, Will of (D Nev, Aug. 25, 2015, No. 3:12–cv–00295-LRH-VPC) 2015 US Dist Lexis 112511</p>
</root>
```

Code:-https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try whether

```
<xsl:param name="pattern1" as="xs:string">((^U\.S\. ex rel )|(^Will of ))</xsl:param>

<xsl:param name="pattern2" as="xs:string">([^v]*?)( v.*)</xsl:param>

<xsl:param name="pattern3" as="xs:string" select="$pattern1 || $pattern2"/>

<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="italic">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $pattern1 || '(.*)', '$4, $2$3')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="italic[matches(., $pattern3)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $pattern3, '$4, $2$3$5')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

helps: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/25

You might need to `normalize-space` the `replace` result of fix the patterns. Also `||` is XPath 3.1, use the `concat` function for XPath/XSLT 2.0.